# What is the word for disingenuous fame chaser? (Different word than sellout)

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m searching for the word that means sellout, or maybe it means the action of selling out. I couldn’t find it on a thesaurus. It’s a bit of an urbandictionary type of word, commonly used to describe disingenuous grifters.

example sentence usage (although I can’t remember if it’s a verb, noun, or adjective):

> That guy really panders to his audience for money. He is a sellout. Yeah, he’s a _____.

synonyms: grifter, sellout, panderer

Comment: "Meretricious" literally means prostituting oneself, and more figuratively suggests lacking integrity and actual value.

Comment: We're to guess at a single elusive target word, which you'll know when you see it? Sorry; all that springs to mind is a list of living examples.

Comment: I think you are under a misapprehension about the meaning of disingenuous.

Comment: @xanne please go on, I don’t follow. Does it not mean “not sincere / not genuine”? (The dictionary confirms it does?)

Comment: The disingenuous person wants you to believe they’re sincere. That’s different from betrayal or simply social climbing or dealing with disregard for others.

Comment: I see. There's no difference in this context, and the pretending to be sincere part is an essential part of how I intended to use the word. But interesting to hear others perceive there being an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a disingenuous fame chaser might be referred to as either a ***social climber*** or a ***clout chaser***.  The former is probably a more widely accepted term; the latter is more of a slang term, but also more specifically disingenuous.

---

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/social%20climber) defines "**social climber**" as:

> one who attempts to gain a higher social position or acceptance in fashionable society

with an example of "*At first glance, this version of Marion echoes the talentless social climber Susan Alexander, Charles Foster Kane’s mistress and second wife in Citizen Kane, widely believed to have been based on her.*"

[Oxford (via Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/social_climber) defines it as:

> *derogatory*: A person who is eager to gain a higher social status.

---

"**Clout chaser**" doesn't show up in any standard dictionaries, but it's fairly commonly used (especially [in the American rap music industry](https://www.quora.com/What-on-Earth-is-a-clout-chaser-and-who-came-up-with-the-term)), with over 250k hits on Google Search.

It's defined by [Slangit](https://slangit.com/meaning/clout_chaser) as:

> someone who does and says things for the purpose of becoming more popular

and by [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Clout%20Chaser) (whose definitions one should generally take with a grain of salt, hence mentioning it second) as:

> a person who strategically associates themselves with the success of a popular person or a currently contemporary trend to gain fame an attention

Comment: Yes, clout chaser was it. Thanks you!